# Set Airflow Graph View BranchOperator Task Order?

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a DAG which uses the BranchPythonOperator for selecting tasks to run. In the graph view, the [vertical] order of those tasks doesn't seem to be deterministic, and more importantly I'd like to be able to set it. Is there a way to do that? For example, in the image below, I'd like to specify that "dont_train" is below "train" and that the order of deploy tasks from top to bottom should be "deploy_model", "deploy_image", "dont_deploy".

[image]

Simplified version of the relevant portion of the DAG:

```
def should_train(**context):
    should_train = context["dag_run"].conf.get("TRAIN", False)
    return "train" if should_train else "dont_train"


with DAG(
    dag_id="some_dag",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 14),
    catchup=False
) as dag:
    t_should_train = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id="should_train",
        python_callable=should_train,
        provide_context=True,
    )

    t_train = DummyOperator(task_id="train")
    t_dont_train = DummyOperator(task_id="dont_train")

    t_should_train >> [t_train, t_dont_train]
```

Currently running Airflow v1.10.10.

Comment: What is top to bottom? Either tasks can run in parallel or they can't.

Comment: I'm asking only about how to change the visualization order in the UI. Also, these aren't parallel tasks in the typical sense - they're branches.

Comment: You can't control over that. It has no logical meaning. When you branch -  One branch will be running - the others will be skipped. I'm a bit confused about what you actually want to achieve. If your question is "my workflow logic is fine, works as expected im just not happy with how it looks in the UI" - there is nothing to do here. If you have an actual logical problem like: task begin executed at wrong order - please explain further what exactly is the issue.

Comment: It's only about how it looks in the UI. That said, it's a bit more than just me "not being happy" - it's a barrier to easy understanding as the number of tasks increases. If it's not possible, though, it is what it is. Thanks.

Comment: I do not think you have the control on the graph visualization.  Airflow using dagre-d3 for graph view and afaik, dagre-d3 is "automatic" rendering and not taking constraints in node order in the same layer.  Some related issue in dagre itself is discussed in a few PR/Issues.  one example: https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre/pull/302

Comment: Thanks for the context @Emma - that explains it.

Comment: @ZaxR For number of tasks increasing you have a new feature in Airflow 2 called TaskGroup which was designed to group tasks by context only for visualization. see http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#taskgroup

Comment: @Elad - yeah that's a good possibility in the future. Right now I'm using Google Composer, which doesn't offer v2.0 yet. One day...